# Javascript/jquery setTimeout gets faster

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout, keyup

I have a bit of code which is a simple counter that starts counting from 0 once spacebar keyup event happens

**JavaScript/jQuery**

```
var position = 0;
$(document).on(
    'keyup',
    function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 32) {
            count();
        } 
    }
);

function count() {
    if(position < 1000){
        $('.counter').text(position);
        position++;
        setTimeout(function() {
            count();
        }, 500);
    }
}
```

However while this is running, whenever I press the spacebar again, the increment gets faster and faster the more I press space. Can someone explain to me what is happening here and a way it can be fixed? Here is a link to example code
https://jsfiddle.net/hh9doqvb/

Comment: what should happend when you press the space second time....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because each time, you press a space you are initiating a new counter

```js
var position = 0,
  timer;
$(document).on('keyup', function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 32) {
    if (timer) {
      clearTimeout(timer);
    }
    //if you want to reset the counter when second space is pressed
    position = 0; 
    count();
  }
});

function count() {
  if (position < 1000) {
    $('.counter').text(position);
    position++;
    timer = setTimeout(count, 500);
  } else {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = undefined;
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  min-height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="counter"></span>
<input />
```

---

If you want to ignore the second space onward then

```js
var position = 0,
  timer;
$(document).on('keyup.space', function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 32) {
    count();
    $(document).off('keyup.space');
  }
});

function count() {
  if (position < 1000) {
    $('.counter').text(position);
    position++;
    timer = setTimeout(count, 500);
  } else {
    timer = undefined;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="counter"></span>
<input />
```